# How $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon}\right]^{1/\log\log n}=e^{1+\varepsilon}\implies a_n=O(n^\varepsilon\log^{1+\varepsilon}n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, limsup-and-liminf

**Question**

Let $(a_n) \subseteq \mathbb R_+$ be a sequence of non-negative numbers such that
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left[ \frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon} \right]^{1/\log \log n} = e^{1+\varepsilon}
$$
for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

Why does it follow that $a_n = O(n^\varepsilon \log^{1+\varepsilon} n)$ ?

---

**Thoughts/Attempt**

By definition of big-O notation and the non-negativity of $(a_n)$, we need to show $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon \log^{1+\varepsilon} n} < \infty$.

I'm trying to manipulate $\frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon \log^{1+\varepsilon} n}$ to make use of the given limes superior. For example,
$$
b_n := \frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon \log^{1+\varepsilon} n} = \frac{ \left( \left[ \frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon} \right]^{1/\log \log n} \right)^{\log \log n} }{ \log^{1+\varepsilon} n}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log b_n &= \log \log (n) \cdot \log\left[ \Big( \frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon} \Big)^{1/\log \log n} \right] - (1+\varepsilon) \log \log (n) \\
&= \log \log (n) \cdot \Big[ \log\left[ \Big( \frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon} \Big)^{1/\log \log n} \right]  - (1+ \varepsilon)\Big].
\end{aligned}
$$
The limes superior of the factor in the square brackets converges to $0$, since
$$
\begin{aligned}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \Big[ \log\left[ \Big( \frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon} \Big)^{1/\log \log n} \right]  - (1+ \varepsilon)\Big] &=  \log\left[ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \Big( \frac{a_n}{n^\varepsilon} \Big)^{1/\log \log n} \right]  - (1+ \varepsilon) \\
&= \log(e^{1+\varepsilon}) - (1+\varepsilon) = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
But $\log \log n \to \infty$, so it's not clear that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \log b_n = \log(\limsup_{n \to \infty} b_n) < \infty$.

---

**Where this comes from**

I'm reading the paper ["Testing for (in)finite moments"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407615002596) by Lorenzo Trapani, in particular the proof of Theorem 1.

There's a lemma showing that
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left[ \frac{\hat \mu_n }{n^{\frac{k}{\gamma} - 1}} \right]^{1/\log \log n} = e^{k/\gamma} \quad \text{almost surely,}
$$
where $(\hat \mu_n)$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables and $0 < \gamma < k$. (Note: This is a slight modification of the paper's notation. There it's called $\hat \mu_k$, but is in fact a sequence in $n$, where the the dependence on $n$ has been suppressed.)

The author states that this implies that $\hat \mu_n  = O_{\text{a.s.}}\left( n^{\frac{k}{\gamma}-1} \log^{k / \gamma} n \right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. For $a_n  = n^\varepsilon  \log ^{1 + \varepsilon } (n)\log \log (n)$ (with $n\geq 3$) it holds that $$
\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left[ {\frac{{a_n }}{{n^\varepsilon  }}} \right]^{1/\log \log (n)}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left[ {\frac{{a_n }}{{n^\varepsilon  }}} \right]^{1/\log \log (n)}  = e^{1 + \varepsilon } ,
$$ yet $a_n \neq \mathcal{O}(n^\varepsilon  \log ^{1 + \varepsilon } (n))$.